# java.lang.NoClassDefFound error while running app

Tags: java, java-me

I was trying to run an application on my phone, when I got this error:

"This application caused an error and may not function correctly.

java.lang.NoClassDefFound
Error:
com/nokia/mid/ui/lcdui/DisplayStateListener"

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this error?

I am a noob to Java and I have just started learning it at my school. Basically, I am working to make an application compatible with my phone. I will be really grateful to you if you could guide me on how can I proceed.

Here is the link to the file: http://msoft9.com/site_down-java-apps.xhtml?get-file=1648

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application is using the socalled NokiaUI API.
This is a rather old API developed by Nokia containing User-Interface functionality for various things, such as keeping the screen alive or making the MIDlet use the whole screen (FullScreen). It was developed in the MIDP1.0 days before things like FullScreen became possible in MIDP2.0

I'm guessing that `DisplayStateListener` is a class in NokiaUI.

Your phone apparently doesn't support NokiaUI. Not all phones does. It **is** supported by other brands than Nokia though. I know that Sony Ericsson phones support the NokiaUI API.

Even today NokiaUI is still used by JavaME developers, because it is (surprisingly/sadly) still the only way to keep the screen alive. But mostly you won't notice it is used, because developers naturally use a try/catch block to utilize it.

That's obviously not what the developers has done in your case.
But you can probably find another version of the MIDlet that doesn't use NokiaUI.

More about NokiaUI API:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Nokia_UI_API

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this question. Is there any way in which I can remove the DisplayStateListener class and the app can still work?

Comment: It would probably be possible to decompile it and remove yes, but it would require some effort. Why don't you just try one of the other versions? What phone do you have? http://www.wechat.com/en/download.html